# how to get filename from the path

Tags: android

i want to show the filename from the full path. i m getting the full path but don't know how to get that file name with extension?
please show me by some example.

code which i use to get full path of the file:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Log.i("On onActivityResult", "get path");
    Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
    try {
        String filemanagerstring = selectedVideoUri.getPath();
            String selectedVideoPath = getPath(selectedVideoUri);
        if (selectedVideoPath != null) {
        filePath = selectedVideoPath;
        Log.i("VideoFilePath", "" + filePath);
        } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
        filePath = filemanagerstring;
        Log.i("FilePath", "" + filePath);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
            Log.i("FilePath", "" + filePath);
        }
```

Comment: what code u had used for get path.....?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, where `path` is the entire filename including parent directories:

```
path.getName()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
selectedVideoUri.getLastPathSegment()
```

Comment: means you got "1".. just print your path and check.